# "public" role access in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Can anybody let me know that what permission does public have in sql server.

Thanks

Comment: Every SQL Server login belongs to the public server role. When a server principal has not been granted or denied specific permissions on a securable object, the user inherits the permissions granted to public on that object. Only assign public permissions on any object when you want the object to be available to all users. You cannot change membership in public.

Note: public is implemented differently than other roles, and permissions can be granted, denied, or revoked from the public fixed server roles.

Answer (score 14):

By default the public role can't do anything*.  Some DBAs will grant the public role additional rights (to see or change data or run stored procs) if they want everyone to have those rights.

`*` -- Well, almost anything.  They can look at some system views and run queries that don't touch any data (like "select 'a'").

To see the specific rights, right click on the role (In SQL 2005 it's Databases > {Your Database} > Security > Roles > Database Role) and select Properties.

Edit: You might also want to check out the server-level public role.  Which is at Security > Server Roles > public

Answer (score 8):

Every database user belongs to the public database role.

When a user has not been granted or denied specific permissions on a securable object, the user inherits the permissions granted to public on that object.

The public server role is granted VIEW ANY DATABASE permission and the CONNECT permission on the default endpoints.

Actually, The public server role is not a fixed server role, because the permissions can be changed, but every user belongs to the public database role by default.

you can check this here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx