# "public" SQL user always given EXECUTE & SELECT permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Whenever I add a basic SQL 2008 user to the server and map it to a particular database with Public access, the user has the effective permission as EXEC and SELECT.

This is only happening in one database.  I have checked the SQL Management interfaces and affirmed that that there is no explicit granting at the DB or Server level for this newly created user.  The default schema for the user is dbo.

I have read the settings as described in: ["public" role access in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410396/public-role-access-in-sql-server), to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create your own database role and assign permissions accordingly, that way you control the access on the database explicitly.

In regards to the Public role, the server administrator can set the permissions for the Public role and these inherit to all the databases so you are best to only use it if you control the server in my opinion.

Hope this helps

AJ

Comment: Good suggestion on the custom role.  Our 'public' account doesn't have any explicit setting on the server level; furthermore, this only seems to occur on one specific database.  We are planning to just rebuild/migrating the entire db.